# Migrations not working on azure and django

Tags: python, django, azure, ssh

i'm facing some problems with Django on my azure resource group. The landing page of my software is working fine, but when i try to log in, it does not work, and i get the error that it has ben caused by the "Accounts application"

```
Error:
relation "accounts_user" does not exist
LINE 1: ...s_user"."admin", "accounts_user"."timestamp" FROM "accounts_...
```

I've performed the migrations on the SSH, but i think that they are not being properly migrated, since even when i "Create a superuser" the user that i've just created does not work to log in and throw the same error.

[image: SSH Migration screen]

Although the variables for the database seem to be sent correctly, as i can see on the local variables on the error:

```
ignored_wrapper_args    
(False,
 {'connection': <django.db.backends.postgresql.base.DatabaseWrapper object at 0x7a01ddf85cc0>,
  'cursor': <django.db.backends.postgresql.base.CursorDebugWrapper object at 0x7a01d58667a0>})
params  
('USER EMAIL',)
self    
<django.db.backends.postgresql.base.CursorDebugWrapper object at 0x7a01d58667a0>
sql 
('SELECT "accounts_user"."id", "accounts_user"."password", '
 '"accounts_user"."last_login", "accounts_user"."email", '
 '"accounts_user"."full_name", "accounts_user"."active", '
 '"accounts_user"."staff", "accounts_user"."admin", '
 '"accounts_user"."timestamp" FROM "accounts_user" WHERE '
 '"accounts_user"."email" = %s LIMIT 21')
```

And:

```
DATABASES   
{'default': {'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False,
             'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
             'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0,
             'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
             'HOST': 'MY HOST NAME.postgres.database.azure.com',
             'NAME': 'MY DATABASE NAME',
             'OPTIONS': {},
             'PASSWORD': '********************',
             'PORT': '',
             'TEST': {'CHARSET': None,
                      'COLLATION': None,
                      'MIGRATE': True,
                      'MIRROR': None,
                      'NAME': None},
             'TIME_ZONE': None,
             'USER': 'MY USERNAME'}}
```

Does anybody know what is can be?

Answer (score 0):

Few possible reasons why your [Django](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/tutorial-django-app-service-postgres?tabs=clone) migrations may not be working on Azure:

- **Incorrect database connection settings:**
  Make sure that your DATABASES setting in your settings .py file is correct for your Azure database. You can find the correct connection string in the Azure portal.
- **Migrations not applied.** Django migrations must be applied to the database in order for changes to the model to be reflected and `sslmode=require`
- To apply migrations, run the following command from the SSH terminal:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

- The `python manage.py migrate` command created some default tables in our database. which inculdes `accounts_user` from this [reference](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/django-app-using-postgresql-database/).

TO access `account_user` refer this links:

- Django [Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/passwords/) for  User authentication and permissions in web [development](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Authentication)
- Django-user-accounts: User [accounts](https://github.com/pinax/django-user-accounts)

For the above reference django provides a built-in authentication and permissions system that allows you to verify user credentials and define what actions each user is allowed to perform.

- The authentication system is centered around the `User` model, which represents the people interacting with your site.
- Permissions can be assigned to specific users and groups of users.
- Django comes with a set of default permissions for each model, but you can also create custom permissions.
- Permissions can be checked using the `has_perm()` method.

Using the Reference I am able to [migrate](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/django-app-using-postgresql-database/) in Django app using Azure [PostgreSQL](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/msdocs-django-postgresql-sample-app).

`settings .py`

```
DATABASES = {

'default':  {

'ENGINE':  'django.db.backends.postgresql',

'NAME':  os.environ.get('DBNAME'),

'HOST':  os.environ.get('DBHOST'),

'USER':  os.environ.get('DBUSER'),

'PASSWORD':  os.environ.get('DBPASS'),

}

}
```

[image]

[image]